# SQL select available rooms

Tags: sql, postgresql

I work on an hotel app, and I am trying to query my sql db for the available rooms between 2 dates.

The table `rate` looks like this:

| room_id | date | unavailable | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 16/08/2022 | false | 10 |
| 1 | 17/08/2022 | null | 20 |
| 1 | 18/08/2022 | null | 30 |
| 2 | 16/08/2022 | false | 10 |
| 2 | 17/08/2022 | true | 20 |
| 2 | 18/08/2022 | null | 30 |
| 3 | 16/08/2022 | false | 10 |
| 3 | 17/08/2022 | false | 20 |
| 3 | 19/08/2022 | false | 30 |

I am looking for the rooms available between `from` = `16/08/2022` and `to` = `18/08/2022`, i.e. the `room_id`s

- with at least one row for every date between from and to
- where none of these row has `unavailable = true`

**expected output**

| room_id |
| --- |
| 1 |

Comment: I'd have an available column, or perhaps reserved. unavailable is a bit backwards.

Answer (score 2):

use a not exists

```
  with t as (select * from rate 
     where date BETWEEN '2022-08-16' AND '2022-08-18')
    select distinct room_id from t a where not exists 
    ( select 1 from t b where a.room_id = b.room_id
      and b.unavailable = true)
```

Comment: this doesn't work if there is no row for rates on the 2022-08-17

Comment: what does `doesn't work` mean? please provide input and expected output and detail what `doesn't work`. `doesn't work` is not useful at all on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `GROUP BY`where you count the available dates and compare it to the dates you nned,

more complex pattern would need more sophisticated algorithms

> ```
> SELECT "room_id" FROM rooms WHERE  "date" BETWEEN '2022-08-16'::date AND '2022-08-18'::date
> AND ("unavailable" = false OR "unavailable" IS NULL)
> GROUP BY "room_id"
> HAVING COUNT(*) =  EXTRACT(DAY FROM '2022-08-18'::timestamp - '2022-08-16'::timestamp) + 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | room_id |
> | ------: |
> |       1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=abf4221027141387dadbb7407d82fdb3)*

every cimlication has its price in execution time

> ```
> WITH rooms_group as(
> SELECT "room_id", "date", "unavailable", 
> ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY "room_id", "date" ORDER BY CASE "unavailable" WHEN true Then 1
> ELSE 2 END ) rn
> FROM rooms )
> SELECT "room_id" FROM rooms_group WHERE  "date" BETWEEN '2022-08-16'::date AND '2022-08-18'::date
> AND ("unavailable" = false OR "unavailable" IS NULL)
> AND rn = 1
> GROUP BY "room_id"
> HAVING COUNT(*) =  EXTRACT(DAY FROM '2022-08-18'::timestamp - '2022-08-16'::timestamp) + 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | room_id |
> | ------: |
> |       1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=00e2534412816698cb8ced632ba1ce2b)*

Comment: interesting ! I find the count(*) condition a bit weak. For example, it would not work if a room has multiple rates for a given day (it wouldn't make much sense either :)

Comment: your question doesn't mention that there could be multiple roon id on the  same dasy and `with a row for every date between from and to`ecludes multiple rows per day for one room and the query must be rebuild to accomplish that

Comment: I have edited the question. I would prefer to check "there is (at least) a row for every day" rather than "number of rows = number of days"

Comment: that isn't allowed accept one answer and open another question. that is the way to go